# outofmemoryexception on url source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this code that pulls an image down from a url

```
<Window x:Class="ImageTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="http://theworldsnotes.com/images/Spoils_logo_trans.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Works fine in most cases, but some users are experiencing the following exception

```
System.OutOfMemoryException:  There is not enough memory to continue the execution of a program
   vid System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   vid MS.Win32.WinInet.get_InternetCacheFolder()
   vid System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDownload.BeginDownload(BitmapDecoder decoder, Uri uri, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Stream stream)
   vid System.Windows.Media.Imaging.LateBoundBitmapDecoder..ctor(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy requestCachePolicy)
   vid System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
   vid System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy)
   vid System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   vid MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   vid MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertFrom(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture)
   vid System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   vid System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   vid MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32 k, ICollectionView collectionView, Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   vid MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32 k, ICollectionView collectionView)
   vid MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourcePropertyChanged(Object o, String propName)
   vid System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList`1.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
   vid System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEventToList(Object sender, EventArgs args, ListenerList list)
   vid System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.OnPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   vid System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   vid MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   vid System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   vid System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   vid System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   vid System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   vid MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   vid MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   vid System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   vid MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   vid System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   vid MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   vid MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   vid System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   vid System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   vid System.Windows.Application.Run()
```

The user is running Windows 7 64bit, with .net 4.5 installed (applicatoin is .net 4.0).

I had them run the repair tool, and also reinstall .net.

I'm about out of ideas here. I even created an app that just used WebClient to download the images and save them to files, and they came through fine. It's also not just one image url that doesn't work, it's about any image url I can throw at the program(from different domains etc).

The user also has avast and microsoft security essentials, but you'd think that would have blocked the other test app from downloading the images correctly.

Any ideas what might be causing this? I have no clue, seems like a bug, I'm leaning toward graphics card driver issue, but not sure.

Comment: Are you sure that this is connected to the images? Have you tried using local images instead? (Just temporarily as a test)

Comment: If you have access to the local computer where the problem happens then attach a debugger to the process and check what the heap says.

Comment: No I don't have access to the computer, it's on a customers machine.

Comment: There are multiple different images from completely different sources used, that arn't all always being used at the same time.

Comment: I have a program here I'm going to have the user test with. Any ideas for tests would really help https://github.com/kellyelton/OCTGN-ImageTest

Comment: So the guy ran it, and only when it's set to a url does it fail. Loading local copies of the exact same image work fine.